# Proposing a Transfer Function from a Response Graph

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, power-electronics, matlab, process-engineering

I need to propose a transfer function from the following graph. The K value (or amplifier gain?) we were given is 2 and it has a step response of 2 as well. When looking at the graph though it looks as if the K value we were given is incorrect if it has an output voltage of around 5v. Can anyone help me propose a transfer function for this? Or point me to some resources that could show me?

[image: Step Response Graph]

A generic, first order transfer function is expected to be of the form
$$
\frac{K}{\tau s + 1}
$$
and I expected `K = 5/2`.

Comment: The K value is 2 and the driving input step is 2 volts.

Comment: K is in reference to the amplifier gain. Not really sure how to attach an image to this comment. New here

Comment: Additional information is to be directly added to the question using [edit] option below the question. Comments may get deleted automatically and should not be relied on to deliver additional information.

Comment: My reasoning in thinking it was incorrect is that in a generic tranfer function K is the numerator (K/s*tau+1). So how could K be equal to 2 if it is equal to Vout/Vin (5/2)?

Comment: OK. That is why I requested for context on the question. if your problem is solved, please *self answer* the question in sufficient detail, below for people visiting this page in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have to answer rather than comment as I'm a noob as well. Are you asking in general for a transfer function, or are you after some PID controller TF?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4w0rslb04E seems to go into excessive detail (I didn't watch the whole thing) but should cover your question.

Comment: Ah thanks very much, I'll watch that tonight.